# How do I take a Toshiba B-EP2DL barcode printer out of Z-Mode

Tags: printing, zebra-printers

I have 2 Toshiba B-EP2DL barcode printers and one is showing Z-Mode so have to use Zebra compatible drivers to print. I prefer to use the TPCL drivers but cannot find any mention on how to turn off the Zebra emulation. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Where have you found the firmware with z-mode support for this priner. my firmware does not suport z-mode. but i need zpl!
You ca try the BCP Tool Software: https://www.toshibatec.com/download_overseas/printer/setting_tool/BCP_Series/  (Important: To read and write settings with this tool, you have to start your printer in the right mode. for MOST (but not all) settings you need to hold FEED key while turning on.

Comment: I bought it used and this was preinstalled on the printer

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it wasn't easy, but in the meantime I was able to get the ZPL emulations firmware for the printer.

Comment: ... So i found out, the Z-Mode emulation firmware only supports Z-mode, C-mode & ESC-POS. If you want to use TPCL, it is needed to flash the normal Firmware for this printer. Unfortunately firmware is not simply downloadable from toshiba website.

Comment: Okay Thanks. How would you go about getting the firmware in that case?

Comment: unfortunately i do not know, how to send privat messages here ...

Comment: I don't either. Is there a websote that these can be downloaded from or simply a case of contacting toshiba support?

Comment: no website. you can try it with contacting, may be you have luck...

Comment: now i found it also online: https://www.toshibatec.nl/upload/docs/b-ep4dl-g-v25.zip. and the z-mode emulation (which you have on printer), but after chaning, possibly you want back: https://www.toshibatec.nl/upload/docs/b-ep4-emulatie-software-v12.zip (Both NOT for GH42 variant of this printer)

Comment: Thats awesome but looking for the e-p2dl model which I doubt this is compatible

Comment: oh, you are right, i have the 4inch version. here the 2 inch version: B-EP2 Emulation Software E1.2 https://www.toshibatec.nl/upload/docs/b-ep2dl-e12.zip, and B-EP2DL Firmware V2.3  https://www.toshibatec.nl/upload/docs/b-ep2dl-v23.zip , B-EP Z-Mode Files  https://www.toshibatec.nl/upload/docs/b-ep-z-mode2013fw.zip

Comment: Thats a great help thankyou

Answer (score 0):

According to toshiba Z-mode specification:

When printer is OFF:
Hold FEED key and press POWER key until the device starts into "System Mode"
Use FEED / PAUSE keys to navigate to <2>MODE SETTINGS settings
With POWER key you can change settings, between Z-Mode, C-Mode and ESC/POS.

**BUT TCPL is not supported by the ZPL emulation firmware. To use TCPL you need to flash the normal firmware for this device, instead of the emulation firmware!** Unfortunately, Toshiba does not publicly offer download of firmware (for this device). They say you get it from Toshiba support only if you bought from Toshiba, otherwise from the authorized seller, which sold the printer. :(

In my opinion, this is not a good company policy in terms of sustainability and ease of use.

Z-Mode spec:
https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/10967417/z-mode-specification-toshiba-tec-store